# Java synchronized method is not synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, transactional

I have project with JAX-RS, Guice, MyBatis. There is method `getToken()` which is invoked through REST endpoint. It is synchronized to avoid exceptions because of `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)`. However, synchronized method is not safe, different calls may affect data concurrently and exception is thrown:

```
Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
```

I have tried to synchronize by mapper object but it also does not work. The only solution which worked was to remove synchronized and change/remove isolation level. How to make method synchronized?

```java
@Singleton
@Path("/forgottenPath")
public class RestEndpoint {

    @Inject
    private oneService oneService;

    @POST
    @Path("/someAction")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public SomeResponse makeSomeAction() {
        ...
        oneService.makeSomeAction();
        ...
    }
}

public class OneServiceImpl implements OneService {

    @Inject
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    @Override
    public SomeRespose makeSomeAction() {
        ...
        anotherService.getToken());
        ....
    }
}

@Singleton
public class AnotherServiceImpl implements AnotherService {

    @Override
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public synchronized Token getToken() {
        // modifies and retrieves info from database
    }
}
```

Comment: What methods other than getToken() make database calls?

Comment: There are other methods for getting and removing tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about `synchronized` doesn't work properly, it's about how `@Transactional` is implemented.

Long story short: instead of directly calling transactional method (`getToken()` in your case), Spring creates proxy class which replaces all transactional methods with something like this (very simplified):

```
// Generated proxy class (either via AOP, dynamic proxy or bytecode generation)
@Override
public Token getToken() {
    try {
        transactionManager.startTransaction(params);
        // Only this call is synchronized
        return super.getToken();
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        transactionManager.rollback();
        rethrow();
    }
    finally {
        // Not in synchronized method (lock is not held), but changes are not commited yet
        transactionManager.commit();
        transactionManager.closeTransaction();
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239285/spring-transaction-management-using-transactional-vs-using-aop-aopadvisor/29243466#29243466) for more details.

As you can see, firstly transaction is opened and only then your original `getToken()` is called, so in fact, when you try to acquire lock (enter synchronized method), transaction is **already** created. Moreover, when caller exit your `getToken()` method lock is released (exit from synchronized method), but transaction **is not yet commited**. So possible race is here:

Assume first thread opens transaction, hold lock, do stuff with database, exit your original method, release lock and then paused a bit. Then second thread can do the same actions, first thread is awaken and they both try to commit, so one of transactions **should** fail.

Answering your original question, to avoid changing isolation level and allow serialized access you need to synchronize not in your service, but around it.

Three solutions:

1) Make caller method synchronozed (`makeSomeAction` in your case)

2) If you don't want whole method be synchronized, create lock for it:

```
@Override
public SomeRespose makeSomeAction() {
    ...
    // Instance of ReentrantLock
    lock.lock();
    try {
        anotherService.getToken());
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    ....
}
```

3) If you want to encapsulate synchronization logic, create blocking adapter:

```
@Singleton
public class AnotherServiceAdapter implements AnotherService {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherServiceImpl originalService;

    @Override // No transactional here => no aop proxy
    public synchronized Token getToken() {
        // Lock is held before transactional code kicks in
        return originalService.getToken();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to synchronize in makeSomeAction() with synchronized(this), synchronized for method but getting the same: Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions.